# How to add leaning late while calculating backward propagation in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, backpropagation

I heard that while doing backward propagation, the weight will be updated
using learning late and partial derivative.

But I don't know where to put the learning_late parameter in the backward propagation code. And I'm wonder that without settings of learning late,
what is the default learning late?

So, Here is the Code that I want to learn.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class MyNeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        layer_1=nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=2, bias=False)
        weight_1 = torch.tensor([[.3,.25],[.4, .35]])
        
        layer_1.weight = nn.Parameter(weight_1)
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            layer_1,
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
        
        layer_2 = nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=2, bias=False)
        weight_2 = torch.tensor([[.45, .4],[.7, .6]])
        
        layer_2.weight = nn.Parameter(weight_2)
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            layer_2,
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
    
    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.layer1(input)
        output = self.layer2(output)
        
        return output
    
model = MyNeuralNetwork().to("cpu")
print(model)

input = torch.tensor([0.1,0.2]).reshape(1,-1)
target = torch.tensor([0.4,0.6]).reshape(1,-1)

out = model(input)
print(f"output value : {out}")

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
loss = criterion(out, target)
print(f"loss value : {loss}")


model.zero_grad() 
print('↓ layer1.weight before backward propagation ↓')
print(model._modules['layer1']._modules['0'].weight)
print(model._modules['layer2']._modules['0'].weight)
print()

loss.backward() # where can I put the learning late in back propagation.
print('↓ layer1.weight after backward propagation ↓')
print(model._modules['layer1']._modules['0'].weight)
print(model._modules['layer2']._modules['0'].weight)
```

My question's Point is how to add learning late which I want
for train this model.

Comment: The learning rate is usually applied by the optimizer during it's step. You don't seem to have an optimizer defined here. It may be helpful to take a look at the beginner tutorial in the official docs [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html#optimizer)

Comment: Then, How the weight is updated without learning rate during the back propagation?

Comment: Backpropagation is the algorithm to compute the gradient, gradient descent is the actual weight update, only gradient descent uses a learning rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you need to use the the learning rate parameter of the optimizer when you call the optimizer's step function in order to update the weights of your model. Specifically, when you create an optimizer, you'll need to specify a learning rate like this:

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

Then, when you do a training/Testing loop, you'll call the optimizer's step function after the backward pass like this:

```
optimizer.step()
```

This step function will update the weights in the model using the learning rate that you specified. The default learning rate is usually 0.01, but you can change it based on your specific needs.